# Counting Rows In A ListView Where There Are Specific Values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have created a ListView in asp.net using an with an SQLDataSource. I have a column with a list of NULL values that when edited will display wether or not a project is 'completed'. I need to COUNT how many rows within this column display Completed.

I'm pretty new to .net, and the only way I can see how to do it, is when the SQLDataSource is accessed, run an SQLCommand to count entries in the column... Surely this isn't the easy way?

Any Help is as always much appreciated :)

Comment: On which side do you need to perform this calculation? Browser, IIS, DB? At which moment?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using Linq after displaying data in the ListView

```
int count = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        .Where(x => x.SubItems[1].Text.ToString() == "Completed")
        .Count();
```